# Lazy loading Polymer 2.0

Tags: service-worker, polymer-2.x

I am trying to load a html file dynamically using

```js
 Polymer.importHref(['src/testing.html'],function()
         {
           console.log("Loaded without error");
         });
```

While it works locally , it throws the following error when uploaded to firebase 
"GoodMorning-app.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'instanceCount' of undefined"
While searching in the net for the solution, few threads indicated to modify precache-config.js file. So that when Href is called it should not try to reload index.html ("Never understood why"). Did the following change as well in precache-config

```js
module.exports = {
navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/__).*/],
  staticFileGlobs: [
    'bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js',
    'images/*',
    'manifest.json',
  ],
```

Still the same error persists. Any suggestions?

Comment: Documentations says first param of importHref is a string: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/#function-Polymer.importHref

Comment: @PascalL.It same error even when replaced with string

Answer (score 0):

Due to Polymer documentation `Polymer.importHref` usage is:

```
Polymer.importHref(href: string, onload: ?function (!Event): void=, onerror: ?function (!ErrorEvent): void=, optAsync: boolean=)
```

So, href need a string path name. At your example its look like an array. You may use with ES6 script something like :

```
`Polymer.importHref(this.resolveUrl('src/testing.htm'), 
                    ()=>{console.log("Loaded without error") //on succes func },
                    ()=>{console.log("Error while loading")  //on error func })
```

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/#function-Polymer.importHref

Comment: sorry i am getting the similar error again  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'instanceCount' of undefined"

Comment: Here is a discussion on the same, can you please take a look https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/5092

Comment: Is it related with `iron-page?`  If so, please provide more code how you handle if the file does not exist. etc. Have fall back page ? . And It may help to load the page with a variable which contain the file name. You may found a good example at shop-app : https://github.com/Polymer/shop

Comment: File does exist , however the error comes up when it tries to load.  This is the comment mentioned in the thread :            
  "I think this probably has to do with how you are redirecting the links to index.html, so it's importing index.html instead of what you intend if the file is missing. To remedy this, add an exception for a specific pattern, or for links using a file extension."